# Issue while getting the frame of the keyboard

Tags: ios, swift

I have code to calculate the position of keyboard which was working correctly, but after installing Xcode11 beta version the code crashing

```
if let keyBoardPosition = (notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgPointValue {
   if (self.frame.origin.y + self.frame.height) > keyBoardPosition.y {
            self.frame.origin.y -= (self.frame.origin.y + self.frame.height - keyBoardPosition.y)
        }
    }
```

> 'Cannot get value with size 16. The type encoded as {CGRect={CGPoint=dd}{CGSize=dd}} is expected to be 32 bytes'

Comment: What do you think the error means? If you look at your code and what the error is saying can you see any possible reason why you are getting it?

Answer (score 4):

`UIResponder.keyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey` returns a **`NSRect`** **NOT** a `CGPoint`:

> The key for an NSValue object containing a CGRect that identifies the
>   starting frame rectangle of the keyboard in screen coordinates. The
>   frame rectangle reflects the current orientation of the device.

For example in iPhone X portrait mode, it is:

```
AnyHashable("UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey"): NSRect: {{0, 896}, {414, 243}}
```

Use this instead:

```
if let keyBoardPosition = (notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? CGRect)?.origin {
        if (self.frame.origin.y + self.frame.height) > keyBoardPosition.y {
            self.frame.origin.y -= (self.frame.origin.y + self.frame.height - keyBoardPosition.y)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you it worked for me but I am wondering how it was working before update to Xcode 11. by the way thank you.